# Any Active Record like gems can do the operations in Ruby object without accessing database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, orm

I need to do lots of queries for rendering a page.

For example, Flight.where(~~~~) that kind of queries is about thousands on rendering a page. However, the involved data is small, only thousands of objects.

I think If I can make those requests on memory instead of the accessing database.
It will be much faster.

Is there any gem to mock Active Record search syntax for Rails?

Therefore, I won't have to write a bunch of `if-else, loop` logic to filter the items.

Currently, I'm using Mongoid for accessing MongoDB on my Rails app

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked into writing scopes? and also yes, that's what `arel` is for :) Finally - are you *really* sure that making requests in-memory is quicker than SQL (I ask because almost always it's not)? Perhaps I'm misunderstanding you... can you give a bit more of an example, and what the problem is? Show us some real code and we might be able to come up with a better solution for you.

Comment: yes, I've tried scope. But I think that's like a alias for doing some queries. I think accessing in memory may quicker is that I saw it takes hundreds ms for a query but it takes thousands times of queries so the response is so slow.

Comment: Have you tried putting all your records in a `yaml` file and then reading them in a hash and iterating/querying over them?

Comment: @aliibrahim That is what I wanna do. however, I also want to keep the AR, or MOngoid search functions instead of building manual search like iterating

Comment: if you have thousands of queries... then it means you aren't doing the eager-loading that you could be doing... How about you give us an example of an actual query that you are trying to create, and we can suggest how to do it in Rails.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ActiveHash` gem as base class instead of `ActiveRecord`.

`ActiveHash` is a simple base class that allows you to use a ruby hash as a readonly datasource for an ActiveRecord-like model.

More details [here](https://github.com/zilkey/active_hash).